# How does transaction propagation impact update in the database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I am trying to understand the behavior of transaction propagation using SpringJTA - JPA - Hibernate.

Essentially I am trying to update an entity. To do so I have written a test method where I fetch an object using entity manager (em) find method ( so now this object is manged object). Update the attributes of the fetched object. And then optionally make a call to service layer(service layer propagation=required) which is calling em.merge

**Now I have three variations here :**

1. Test method has no transactional annotation. Update the attributes
   of the fetched object and make no call to service layer.

   1.1.  Result level 1 cache doesn't gets updated and no update to DB.
2. Test method has no transactional annotation. Update the attributes of the fetched object. Call the service layer.

   2.1. Result level 1 cache and DB gets updated.
3. Test method has Transnational annotation which could be any of the following. Please see the table below  for Propagation value at the test method and the outcome of a service call.

[image]

*(service layer propagation=required)*

So to read the above table, the row 1 says if the Test method has transaction propagation= REQUIRED and if a service layer call is made then the result is update to Level 1 cache but not to the DB

Below is my test case

```
    @Test

    public void testUpdateCategory() {
//Get the object via entity manager
        Category rootAChild1 = categoryService.find(TestCaseConstants.CategoryConstant.rootAChild1PK);
        assertNotNull(rootAChild1);
        rootAChild1.setName(TestCaseConstants.CategoryConstant.rootAChild1 + "_updated");

// OPTIONALLY call update
    categoryService.update(rootAChild1);

//Get the object via entity manager. I believe this time object is fetched from L1 cache. As DB doesn't get updated but test case passes
Category rootAChild1Updated = categoryService.find(TestCaseConstants.CategoryConstant.rootAChild1PK);
        assertNotNull(rootAChild1Updated);
        assertEquals(TestCaseConstants.CategoryConstant.rootAChild1 + "_updated", rootAChild1Updated.getName());
        List<Category> categories = rootAChild1Updated.getCategories();
        assertNotNull(categories);
        assertEquals(TestCaseConstants.CategoryConstant.rootAChild1_Child1,categories.get(0).getName());
    }
```

**Service Layer**

```
 @Service
    public class CategoryServiceImpl implements CategoryService {   
        @Transactional
        @Override
        public void update(Category category) {
            categoryDao.update(category);
        }
    }
```

**DAO**

```
 @Repository
    public class CategoryDaoImpl {
    @Override
        public void update(Category category) {
            em.merge(category);
        }
    }
```

**Question**
Can someone please explain why does REQUIRED, REQUIRES_NEW, and NESTED doesn't lead to insertion in the DB?

And why absence of transaction annotation on Test case lead to insertion in the DB as presented in my three variations?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect you're seeing for `REQUIRED`, `NESTED`, and `REQUIRES_NEW` is due to the fact that you're checking for updates **too early**

(I'm assuming here that you check for db changes at the same moment when the test method reaches the assertions, or that you roll the test method transaction back somehow after executing the test)

Simply enough, your assertions are still within the context created by the `@Transactional` annotation in the test method. Consequently, the implicit flush to the db has not been invoked yet.

In the other three cases, the `@Transactional` annotation on the test method does **not** start a transaction for the service method to join. As a result, the transaction only spans the execution of the service method, and the flush occurs **before** your assertions are tested.

Comment: Regarding "I am assuming", I am checking DB after the test case ends and test case ends successfully so there is no roll back happening. After the test case ends , implying transaction has ended, shouldn't  be flush before the transaction ends.

Comment: Spring rollbacks transactional tests by default. Are you sure you disabled that behavior?

Comment: spring default rollbacks were causing me not to see the proper results.